# Why does int 3 generate a SIGSEGV in 64-bit instead of stopping the debugger?

Tags: debugging, assembly, signals, x86-64

In 32 bits mode programming I used to employ `int 3` in my programs a lot for stopping at a given location with the debugger (embedding the instruction in the source). Now in 64 bits it seems to not be working, producing a very ordinary SIGSEGV under gdb and destroying the program beyond hope ("Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists."). I wonder if 64 bit mode has another mechanism, or if I should do some cache-flush (the `int 3` is a dynamically generated opcode in this case (0xcc), is some jit-like code).

Comment: Note that with some assemblers (like NASM), `int 3` is `CD 03`, and you need to write `int3` (no space) to get the `0xCC`  single-byte opcode.  According to [Intel's manual for int n / int3](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INTn:INTO:INT3:INT1.html), the difference actually matters in vm86 mode.  But yes, Intel's manual does confirm that it behaves the same in 64-bit mode, so any difference in behaviour is up to the kernel and/or the debugger.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following code will work on an `amd64` UNIX platform:

*breakpoint.c*

```
int main() {
    int i;     
    for(i=0; i<3;i++) {
        __asm__("int3");
    }
}
```

Compile it trivially: `gcc -c breakpoint.c` and start `gdb a.out`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00000000004004fb in main ()
```

You see, gdb stops at the breakpoint.

Comment: You should say the kernel version instead of just date :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 Good point. Unfortunately I cannot surely say it any more. The only thing I surely know is that is was a 3.x.y kernel. My current kernel is 3.19.0 and it still works.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong: BarsMonster's answer is about Win64, while you demonstrate the functionality on a UNIX-like system (or at least non-MS toolchain if on Win64).

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 20):

__debugbreak()

> Today a colleague came by to ask about
>   how to get "int 3" functionality on
>   the 64bit platforms.  What is "int 3"?
>   It's the assembly instruction that is
>   used to create a breakpoint.  At least
>   that's the instruction for the x86
>   processor, and as you can imagine it
>   is very platform specific.
>
> On the 64bit platforms there is no
>   inline assembly, so there goes your
>   "__asm int 3".  What to do now?  Well
>   there's a lesser known construct which
>   is actually much better to use in that
>   it works across all platforms (x64,
>   Itanium, and x86), which is
>   __debugbreak().  This is a Visual C++ compiler intrinsic (defined in Visual
>   C++ 2005 under vc\include\intrin.h,
>   with tons of other cool intrinsics)
>   that will effectively act "int 3"
>   across all platforms.
>
> DebugBreak, the Win32 function call is
>   still around, but in general using
>   __debugbreak() is my preference, if for no other reason than it's not a
>   function call (it's a compiler
>   intrinsic), and you don't need debug
>   symbols to get a readable call stack.
>
> If you're writing C++ you probably
>   don't want to write non-portable
>   assembly, and this is just one less
>   place where you would have to.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kangsu/archive/2005/09/07/462232.aspx

Comment: This is a very informative answer, but as I specified in my question, I was generating code dynamically, and that rules out compiler intrinsics. Not to mention that my usual compiler is not Visual C++, neither my platform Windows. Furthermore, the answer is inaccurate because int 3 does exist and at least in 64 bits linux  behaves as usual. Also, depending in the compiler, you do have inline assembly in 64 bits mode.

Comment: That's fine for MS IDEs, but what if I am using Eclipse and GCC?

Answer (score 13):

Ahh, I got it, sorry. I had to unprotect the pages for execution. Int 3 is still a valid debug trap.

Comment: This question was seven years ago, so it's hard to remember the details of what I did. I do remember that is was quite straightforward, I think I was calling mmap(2) and just added the PROT_EXEC flag. Or was it mprotect(2) ... ?

Comment: Presumably execution was never reaching the `int3` because the code was in a read/write / no-exec page.  So merely jumping there caused a segfault, regardless of the contents.  And yes, `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE` for mmap should be right approach.  Or you could start off with a read/write page, then flip it to read/exec with mprotect after you're done, so you never have a write+exec page mapped (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you never use `asm int 3` as it works for all build types. You might forget a line somewhere in your code and that can mean big troubles. The alternative is to use [__debugbreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak) which is only valid in debug mode.

Comment: While I also would recommend `__debugbreak` (if available) over `asm int 3`, I do not think your assumption is right. `__debugbreak` seems to always have effect, not only in debug mode, but also in release mode.